# Add a conditional foreign key field in a DJANGO model

Tags: python, django

**Models.py** is shown below. The Release table has a foreign key **system_requirements_id** that points to the **SystemRequirement** table but I want that the user should fill the **system_requirements_id** *only when there is no text in the system_requirements field* in the Release table. Otherwise, the **system_requirements_id** can be left blank. How do I implement that?

```
class SystemRequirement(TimeStampedModel):
    code_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code_name

class Release(TimeStampedModel):
    system_requirements = models.TextField(blank=True)
    system_requirements_id = models.ForeignKey(SystemRequirement,
    blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: what behavior/error is seen with the above code?

Comment: There is no error. I want to implement that functionality and I don't know how to do it in django.

Comment: You should add this to clean method on your form/model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is:-

Models.py -

```
class Release(TimeStampedModel):
    system_requirements_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    system_requirements = models.TextField(blank=True)



class SystemRequirement(TimeStampedModel):
    system_requirements_id = models.ForeignKey(Release)
    code_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code_name
```

views.py-(Query)

```
#check system_requirements text in Release table
try:
    SystemRequirement =     Release.objects.get(system_requirements='MatchingText')

    #If got matching result means text exist so don't do anything

except ObjectDoesNotExist: #No matching query
    Release.objects.filter(system_requirements='MatchingText').update(system_requirements_id='SomeId')
```

Comment: Why have you used UUID Field. Does it serve any special purpose?

Comment: UUID function creates 128 bit unique id.(Mostly use for the PK).

Comment: Can't we use AutoField instead of UUID Field?

Comment: Yes we can, except autofield you have this.

Comment: Does this answer helps you?